# Use Docker DNS server on other nodes

Tags: docker

The new version of Docker (version 1.10) includes a DNS server to pass alias information from other hosts on the same network. There used to be hosts file entries for resolving linked containers (or containers on the same network). I am wondering if it is possible to use this embedded DNS server on an overlay network? I have looked in the documentation (and in issues) and cannot find information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way the new embedded DNS "server" works is that it isn't a formal server. It's just an embedded listener for traffic to `127.0.0.11:53` (udp of course). When docker sees that query traffic on the container's network interface, it steps in with its embedded DNS server and replies with any answers it might have to the query. [The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) has some options you can set to affect how this DNS server behaves, but since it only listens for query traffic on that localhost address, there is no way to expose this to an overlay network in the way that you are thinking. However [this seems to be](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19474) a moving target, and I have seen this question before in IRC, so it may one day be the case that this embedded DNS server at least becomes pluggable, or possibly exposable in the way you would like.